# Handle displaying uint8 as an int automatically to an ostream

Tags: c++, int, ostream

I have a class with a member of type uint8 and when I try to output it to an ostream it displays as it's char representation.  I would prefer it's int representation so I need to static_cast(myStruct.member) each time which is a bit cumbersome and potentially error-prone.  Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not sure you can overload the `<<` operator for such a native type but perhaps you could overload `<<` to support displaying your specific structure ?

Comment: After considering the question a bit longer, I could override operator<< for uint8 however I'm worried about side-effects in the rest of the codebase.  If there was only a way to limit the scope of the override to my specific namespace or files it would be fine.

Comment: I advise against this, having made this mistake before. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `operator<<` on your class and define the cast there.  Seems to me like you are violating encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
class X {
  uint8 a;
  int get_int () const { return static_cast<int>(a); }
};
```

Us a wrapper method which encapsulate the casting inside.
Usage:

```
cout << obj.get_int();
```

Comment: Even if the call is likely to get inlined, if `a` is best represented as a `int` why isn't it an `int` in the first place ?

Comment: @ereOn, agree. But may be the OP wants to present `int` format only for display purpose

Comment: Indeed. But if the purpose is only "display", wouldn't `std::string` be a better fit instead of `int` ? (`boost::lexical_cast<>` would help there)

Comment: @ereOn - Obviously the OP needs to store a HUGE number of these values, and don't want to move a  lot of 0's around.